# Mensagem java script repetitivas

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou fazendo um sistema de login e esta acontecendo que toda vez que o usuario aperta no botão de conectar(enviar) as mensagem se acumula, sendo que o objetivo era somente aparecer uma vez toda vez que o usuario clica de no botão conectar.

```js
(document).ready(function(){
 $("#conectar").click(function(){
  var user = $("#user").val();
  var senha = $("#senha").val();
  // Checking for blank fields.
  if( user =='' || senha ==''){
   $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css("border","2px solid red");
   $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css("box-shadow","0 0 3px red");
   $("#mensagem").addClass("alert alert-danger").append("<strong>Cuidado!</strong> Certifique que os dados estejam inseridos");
  }else {
   $.post("logar.php",{ user: user, senha :senha},
   function(data) {
    if(data == 0) {
     $('input[type="text"]').css({"border":"2px solid red","box-shadow":"0 0 2px red"});
     $('input[type="password"]').css({"border":"2px solid red","box-shadow":"0 0 2px red"});
     $("#mensagem").addClass("alert alert-danger").append("<strong>OPS!</strong> Usuário ou Senha Inválida");
    }else if(data ==1){
     window.location.href = "areaUsuario.php";
    } else{
     alert(data);
    }
  });
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<form action="logar.php" class="form-horizontal"  method="post">
  <div class="form-group box-1">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <input class="form-control" id="user" type="text" name="user" placeholder="E-mail ou Usuário" required />
    <input id="senha" class="form-control" type="password" name="senha" value="" placeholder="Senha" required/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12 box-1">
    <button type="button" id="conectar" name="conectar" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-12">conectar</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12 box-1">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
     <a href="recuperar.php">Recuperar Acesso</a>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-sm-6">
     <a href="cadastro.php">Cadastre-se</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12" id="mensagem" role="alert">
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onde estiver usando o `.append` substitua por `.html`:

```
$("#mensagem").addClass("alert alert-danger").html("<strong>OPS!</strong> Usuário ou Senha Inválida");
```

O método `append` acrescenta no elemento a string passada como parâmetro. O comportamento que você espera é que a mensagem antiga seja sobrescrita com a nova, que é o que o método `html` faz.

Leia mais em:

- [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)